# How to read integers till end of line?

Tags: c++, input

I'm trying to do bfs on graph,given an adjacency list.
Here's a sample input.

```
1 2 3
2 4
1
2 3 4
```

I know the number of lines,n (number of verices).
Each line contains 0 to n-1 integers.

This was an attempt but it doesnt work as it reads all the integers till the end of the input.

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   while(cin>>v)
   {insert(i,v);}
}
```

I want to process each line separately.
On searching, I found answers with vectors and stl.It would be nice if someone could come up with a more elegant solution.

Thanks.

Comment: What was not elegant with using the standard library?  Using it should make the code about 4 lines.

Comment: *"This was an attempt but it doesnt work as it reads all the integers till the end of the input."* - Not true. Post an MCVE to prove that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, read a line with getline:

```
string line;
getline( cin, line );     // should be error handling here
```

Then, read the integers from the line using an istringstream:

```
istringstream is( line );
int n;
while( is >> n ) {
  // do something with n
}
```