# What's going on in this line: istringstream is( line );

Tags: c++

Was reading this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654357/8408220

(to the question "How to read integers till end of line?")

and I don't understand what this line is doing:

```
istringstream is( line );
```

I get that istringstream is a class, but what's the "is" part?

Is it doing this:

```
istringstream is = new istringstream(line);
```

?

Comment: `is` is the name of the variable being declared.

Comment: `is` is the same of the variable. It calls a constructor with `str` as the argument. Your last line is the equivalent in Java.

Comment: I suppose I understood that. I just have never seen a variable taking an argument in a declaration/definition?—if that makes sense.

Comment: Well in Java you can do `String str = new String("hello")`. That's pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @edmqkk "*I just have never seen a variable taking an argument in a declaration*" - then I suppose you havent been around C++ (or OOP in general) very long, have you? Constructing objects with input arguments is VERY common to do. Here's another example: `string Username("edmqkk");` Exact same concept.

Comment: @RemyLebeau My first snarky comment! \ (•◡•) /
_"...then I suppose you havent been around C++ (or OOP in general) very long, have you?"_ I feel like I'm finally a member of the SO community now. lol. I suppose I should have said, "I've never seen creating a new object without the new keyword."

Comment: @edmqkk welcome to C++. Many different ways to construct objects - automatic vs dynamic, manual vs RAII, etc. Have fun

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you! It _is_ pretty different from Ruby and JavaScript Land. (>﹏<) I'm starting with _Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++_ and _hackerrank.com_. Any other suggestions for a noob?

Comment: @edmqkk [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
istringstream is( line );
```

is a definition of an automatically allocated `istringstream` named `is` initialized with the contents of `line`.

```
istringstream is = new istringstream(line);
```

will not compile. `new` dynamically allocates and constructs a new object and returns a pointer to it. You can only assign a pointer to a pointer. You could

```
istringstream * is = new istringstream(line);
```

and make `is` a pointer to an `istringstream`, but now you have to deal with managing the dynamic allocation. Make sure you

```
delete is;
```

when you no longer need it.

That said, prefer automatic allocation and give [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new) a read before going the dynamic route.